# Unable to Get Storyboarding to work on Powerpoint 2013/VS 2013 Premium

Tags: visual-studio-2013, storyboard, powerpoint

I have MS Office 2013 installed on my PC. I want to use storybord for designing but I am not getting Storybording menu in PowerPoint.  I also have Visual Stuio 2013 Premium which I installed after previously having VS 2013 Team Explorer installed.

So far, I have removed the VS 2013 Team Explorer and Repaired my install of VS 2013.  I cannot get the story boarding tab to show up and when starting a story board from TFS Web Access I get an error.

Does anybody know of a way to enable the storyboarding functionality manually?  All the MS KB articles I find point to installing VS 2011 or higher and it will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've solved your problem by now, but I hit a similar one recently and managed to get it back. It's probably not the exact solution for you but it might help.

I did a VS2013 repair install which you've already done and then restarted my PC and the feature came back. I then looked at the Options -> Add-Ins section of PowerPoint then noticed that the TFS office add-in had been restored under 'COM Add-ins -> Active Application Add-ins' where it wasn't before.

It linked to 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Team Foundation Server\12.0\x86\TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll': your answers may lie on how to get that dll repaired/installed on your system. My guess is that it could be that the software involved was installed in a mix of 32- & 64-bit configurations.